# iOS: Which events that can awake a terminated app?

Tags: ios

In iOS, a user can manually terminate an application by [swiping up the app's preview](https://support.apple.com/en-il/HT201330). Naturally, when the app is terminated, background operations cease to function.

There are some events that can awake a terminated app. One notable example is [a notification from a BLE beacon](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html).

**Is there an official list of events that can wake up a terminated iOS app?**

Comment: Beacons don't wake up an app that is "officially" terminated by swiping it out. It only wakes up an app that is "officially" in the background, but was terminated by the OS.

Comment: @Adam Matan Do you find a solution for your question ?

Comment: @sorunluadam no longer relevant for me, but might as well be relevant for others